# How do i find the second to last symbol?

Tags: regex

```
cmd.Add(new MySqlCommand("CREATE USER u1@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '"+p1+"'", conDatabase););
cmd.Add(new MySqlCommand("CREATE USER u2@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '" + p2+ "'", conDatabase););
```

I have strings like this and i want to find this semicolon conDatabase)**;**); so the one before the last one. So that the result will look this after i delete it.

```
cmd.Add(new MySqlCommand("CREATE USER u1@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '"+p1+"'", conDatabase));
cmd.Add(new MySqlCommand("CREATE USER u2@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '" + p2+ "'", conDatabase));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
;(?=[^;]*;[^;]*$)
```

Try this.See demo.Replace with `empty string`.

http://regex101.com/r/kP4pZ2/20

Answer (score 4):

```
/;(?=[^;]*;[^;]*$)/
```

"There's a semicolon I'm interested in, and after that a string of nonsemicolons, a semicolon, more semicolons and end of line."

But in your case it's overkill. Just replace `;);` with `));`.

Comment: oh right didnt even think about that but i wanted a solution like this so that i would know how to solve more complex cases of the same problem in the future

Comment: Yup, yup, understood.

Comment: @hwnd: As I said, `;);` seems even easier than that, if we restrict it to the OP's examples. But the solutions in the answers are for the most general case for the question implied in the title. Your solution will match *all* semicolons except the one at the end of the line. It will thus match the third from the back as happily as the second-last; and it will match the last one if it is not stuck at the very end.